# How to populate dropdown in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, drop-down-menu

I want top populate dropdown date field in cakephp 2.x.

my date format is 1987-07-05 but when i using cakephp date.

```
echo $this->form->input('birthday', array(
'type' => 'date', 
'id' => 'birthday', 
'required' => false, 
'empty' => array(
    'month' => 'Month', 'day' => 'Day', 'year' => 'Year'
    ), 
'id' => 'birthday', 
'minYear' => date('Y') - 16, 
'maxYear' => date('Y') - 60, 
'label' => FALSE,
'style'=>'width:100px', 
'value'=>$getProfile['Performer_detail']['birthday']
));
```

With the code above, I am getting 3 dropdown fields: `Month`, `Day`, and `Year`: I am also getting `1987-07-05` in `$getProfile['Performer_detail']['birthday']` but these 3 fields are not selected.

Please help me.

Comment: Do not use "value", its best to make the controller populate the dropdown with the right values. See [here](http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/23/working-with-forms/#default-values).

Comment: Gonna have to clarify your question.

Comment: @mark i got my answer. Value must be there. Please check Chinu answer :) It works fine for me.

Comment: No it creates issues with the form when invalidating. Thus the answer is not quite the way one should handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code -

```
<?php echo $this->form->dateTime(
'birthday', 'MDY','', array(
   'id'=>'birthday','value'=>$getProfile['Performer_detail']['birthday'], 'empty' => array('month' => 'Month', 'day' => 'Day', 'year' => 'Year'),'label'=>'','minYear'=>date('Y')-16,'maxYear'=>date('Y')-60
  )
);?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pasting the demo to understand the Date input field in cakephp.

```
table: users
    id         int
    name       varchar
    birthday   date
```

**add.ctp**

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->create();
echo $this->Form->input('name');
echo $this->Form->input('birthday',array('dateFormat' => 'YDM'));
echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

Form will look like this,Notice the values.It will display the current date by default.

[image]

I have added one record with name Kevin and Date **2019-5-September**.Now this is when i edit the same record

[image]

**edit.ctp**

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->create();
echo $this->Form->input('name');
echo $this->Form->input('birthday',array('dateFormat' => 'YDM'));
echo $this->Form->input('id', array('type' => 'hidden'));
echo $this->Form->end('submit');
?>
```

As you can see that in both file add.ctp and edit.ctp file i haven't included extra value for the birthday.Cakephp will autofill the field data in edit form if you have correctly followed the cakephp conventions.So here no need to add the `$getProfile['Performer_detail']['birthday']`